# What is a non-ambiguous CFG for generating the set of natural numbers?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers

I'm trying to write a non-ambiguous context-free grammar that can generate the set of natural numbers, including the 0. My current solution is the following grammar:

$\mathcal{G}: S \rightarrow 0\ |\ ...\ |\ 9\ |\ 1S\ |\ ...\ |\ 9S$

From what I understand, there is not an algorithm to determine whether my guess is correct, thus only I—or you—can convince myself it is (or it is not, of course).

Comment: The set of natural numbers is produced by a regular language, and your grammar is right linear (and therefore regular), so in this particular case a proof is possible.

Answer (score 5):

"From what I understand, there is not an algorithm to determine whether my guess is correct." It looks like your understanding is wrong.

There is no algorithm that determines whether **any** given formal language grammar is ambiguous context-free. There is no algorithm that determines whether **any** given formal language grammar is inherently ambiguous context-free. However, it is possible to decide many particular grammars is (inherently) ambiguous context-free or not by some algorithms.  For example, the trivial algorithm that just outputs "ambiguous context-free" determines the grammar with rules $S\to A|B$, $A\to c$, $B\to c$ as ambiguous context-free. For example, the trivial algorithm that always outputs "not inherently ambiguous context-free" determines all regular grammars as not inherently ambiguous context-free.

As said by rici, your grammar is regular. There is [an algorithm](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/ambiguity-in-regular-and-context-free-languages) that can decide any given regular grammar is ambiguous or not. (Immediately by definition, a regular language is context-free.). As demonstrated by Dmitri Urbanowicz, your grammar is, in fact, not ambiguous.

As said by Dmitri Urbanowicz, your grammar is wrong since it cannot generate number 101. Here is a correct grammar, which can be shown to be non-ambiguous context-free.
$\quad S \to BT|A$
$\quad T \to AT|A$
$\quad A \to B|0$
$\quad B \to 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9$

Answer (score 4):

This grammar is unambiguous, because no pair of productions can lead to the same string. Since $S$ doesn't generate empty string, you either get different first characters or strings of different lengths.

Though this grammar is unable to generate $101$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A possibile solution is also:

$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{G}:\ & S \rightarrow 0\ |\ 1A\ |\ ...\ |\ 9A \\
              & A \rightarrow \varepsilon\ |\ 0A\ |\ ...\ |\ 9A
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Indeed, this one *can* produce $101$!

Comment: It is non-ambiguous as well.